# C++ upgrade to VS2017: error C2668 about ambiguous call

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, ambiguous

I am upgrading an old library from VS2010 to VS2017. I got an error that I managed to fix, but I don’t understand why the fix works.

Below I made a small test that reproduces the error in VS2017. However, if you run this in VS2010, or if you uncomment the copy constructor in the Date class, then it works fine.

The error I get:

```
error.cpp(115): error C2668: 'Date::Date': ambiguous call to overloaded function  
error.cpp(22): note: could be 'Date::Date(Date &&)'  
error.cpp(22): note: or       'Date::Date(const Date &)'  
error.cpp(19): note: or       'Date::Date(std::string)'  
error.cpp(18): note: or       'Date::Date(int)'  
error.cpp(115): note: while trying to match the argument list '(CVariant)'
```

The code

```
#include "stdafx.h"  
#include <string>  
#include <memory>  

class Date  
{
public:
    Date() { date = 19000101; }  

    // Copy constructor
    // The code will not compile in VS2017 if this constructor is not there,
    // But it compiles fine in VS2010
    /*Date(const Date & dt) {
        date = dt.date;
    }*/
    explicit Date(int yyyymmdd) { date = yyyymmdd; }  
    explicit Date(std::string isodate) { date = 19000101; } // Silly  constructor, just for this example  
private:
    int date;
};
enum cvtype {
    mInt,
    mDate,
    mNone
};

class CVariant
{
public:
    CVariant() {}

    // Copy constructor
    CVariant(const CVariant& variant) {
        copy_CVariant(variant);
    }

    // Copy assignment
    CVariant& operator=(const CVariant& variant) {
        copy_CVariant(variant);
        return *this;
    }

    void copy_CVariant(const CVariant& variant)
    {
        switch (variant._type)
        {
        case mInt:
            operator=(variant.value._Int);
            break;
        case mDate:
            operator=(*variant.value.pDate);
            break;
        default:
            clear();
            break;
        }
    }

    // Other constructors
    CVariant(const Date& date_value) : _type(mNone) { operator=(date_value);}  
    CVariant(int int_value) : _type(mNone) { operator=(int_value); }

    // casting
    operator int() const {
        if (_type == mInt) return value._Int;
        else return 0;
    }
    operator Date() const {
        if (_type == mDate) return *value.pDate;
        return Date();
    }

    // Assignment
    CVariant& operator=(int int_value) {
        clear();
        _type = mInt;
        value._Int = int_value;
        return *this;
    }
    CVariant& operator=(const Date& date_value) {
        clear();
        _type = mDate;
        value.pDate = new Date(date_value);
        return *this;
    }

private:
    void clear()
    {
        if (_type == mDate)
            delete value.pDate;
    }

    union VarValue
    {
        int _Int;
        Date* pDate;
    } value;

    cvtype _type;

};

int main()
{
    Date t(20170516);
    int i(10);
    CVariant cvt(t); 
    CVariant cvi(i); 
    // The following line only works in VS2017 if  
    // you uncomment the copy constructor in the Date class   
    // This works fine in VS2010 no matter what
    Date t1(cvt); 
    // This works 
    Date t2 = cvt;
    Date t3 = cvi;
    int i1 = cvt;
    int i2 = cvi;
    Date t4(cvt.operator Date());
    Date t5 = cvt.operator Date();
    int i3 = cvi;
    return 0;
}
```

I believe that I understand the error: when I try to create a Date from a CVariant, there are several conversions possible, each to different Date constructors, so the call is ambiguous.

But why does adding a copy constructor solve this?

Thanks a lot for the help!

P.S. I am aware that using implicit operator conversions, especially those to arithmetic types, is not a good idea, but my first priority is just to get this old library to compile.

Comment: Your comments say that this *won't* compile in VS2017 *unless* you uncomment the copy constructor. Yep your error is from when the copy constructor *is uncommented*. What's going on here?

Comment: I think it's just a bug in VS. It's just that VS2010 was more buggy than VS2017 and as such accepts all cases. I.e. both clang and gcc reject this code due to ambiguities regardless of the presence of the copy constructor. See https://godbolt.org/g/gXttnh

Comment: @Jonathan Mee: Thanks for your reply. It works when the constructor is there, i.e. when I uncomment the code. I get the error when the constructor is commented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The problem

Both the version with and the one without the explicit copy constructor are not valid C++ code, due to ambiguous calls.

It just happens that the MSVC compiler does something "magical" and non-standard to compile it (a common theme with MSVC). If you try any of the other major compilers (gcc, clang, icc, see live example [here](https://godbolt.org/g/ejFBJz)) they all fail to compile it.
I wouldn't rely on such ambiguous code even if it "works", as it might (and probably will) stop working with another compiler version, or different compiler.

The ambiguity comes from the way C++ ranks potential implicit conversion sequences: it always tries to do the minimal amount of them, and at most a single user-defined conversion. The standard describes this process in more detail in [**[class.conv]**](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.conv).

In your case, when calling `Date t1(cvt);` there are two ways to resolve the call, each of them requiring exactly one user-defined conversion (and no other conversions):

1. Conversion from `CVariant` to `int` (`CVariant::operator int()`), followed by a call to `Date::Date(int)`.
2. Conversion from `CVariant` to `Date` (`CVariant::operator Date()`), followed by a call to (implicit) copy constructor `Date::Date(const Date &)`.

### The solution

There are several ways to solve this issue:

1. Add the [`explicit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) keyword to one of the CVariant conversions, so it will no longer participate in implicit conversions.
2. Specify which conversion you want at the call site (e.g. `Date t1(static_cast<Date>(cvt)` to use `CVariant::operator Date()`).
3. Add a conversion constructor from `CVariant` to `Date` (`Date::Date(const CVariant &)`), which will make this constructor require no conversions, so the compiler will prefer this one instead of the other two.

#### How to implement option 3

See full example [here](https://godbolt.org/g/5YYQGi).

In short you need to do the following:

- forward-declare `CVariant` so its name is available when creating the conversion constructor in `Date`
- add a declaration of the constructor to `Date`
- define the constructor after `CVariant` has been defined, so you can use the conversion from `Cvariant` to `Date` in the implementation of the constructor

Here are the relevant changes to the code:

```
class CVariant;

class Date  
{
public:
    // [...]
    explicit Date(const CVariant &cvt);
    // [...]
};

class CVariant
{
    // [...]
};


Date::Date(const CVariant &cvt) : Date(cvt.operator Date()) {}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was hoping I could avoid option 1 or 2 to solve this, because it involves adding casts to a lot of lines. I actually tried option 3 myself, but I got into problems due to cyclic dependencies: creating a Date from a CVariant and a CVariant from a Date. I can’t see how to get around that?

Comment: that's actually the cause why VS worked, VS2010 could do as many 
implicit  conversions as was required. I ran into something similar when tried to debug  and refactor code that involved several classes that contained different data in fields inherited from base to which they could be converted (I know, it's bad! author did not know), while using operator that were defined for other classes

Comment: @Nele I've updated my answer with a working implementation of option 3.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've added it to the big library (and removed this copy constructor) and it compiled just fine.

Comment: @Nele if this answer solved your problem, you may consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). It gives me rep, and more importantly, tells other users "this one works".

Comment: So you're hypothesis here is that gcc is behaving correctly by considering constructor selection ambiguous, even though the `explicit`  is there and one of the constructors it is considering is not viable?

Comment: I'm not trying to say "this is correct because gcc works that way", but because that's what is defined in the standard. However, noting that not only gcc, but also clang and icc handle it the same way does support my interpretation of the standard.

Comment: @GoranFlegar Did you have a quote on that? Seems like explicit should prevent that?

Comment: @JonathanMee about the `explicit` keyword, you are interpreting it the wrong way. If you have `struct A {}; struct B { explicit B(A) {} };` it means that the constructor `B::B(A)` will not participate in implicit conversions (e.g. `B x; x = A{};` will fail to compile).  However, it does not prevent implicit conversion that don't require this constructor. For example in the context `B x(expression);` all implicit conversions that lead `expression` to be converted to an object of type`A` will be considered.

Comment: I'll try finding the appropriate quote, but cannot promise anything - knowing the standard this is buried somewhere under 10 pages of definitions with cross-references to another 10 chapters :/

Comment: @JonathanMee maybe it would be a better idea if you ask a separate question about the correct interpretation of `explicit` (and tag it with language-lawyer). I cannot put quotes in the comments even if I found one, and you'll have more chances of getting an appropriate quote from people that know more about the standard than I do.